# Approx how long will it take to go to Cologne Bonn Airport from Cologne city center?

Tags: germany, airport-transfer, cologne, cgn

I will be attending [Symfony Day 2011](http://www.symfonyday.com) which will be held at [Komed Im Mediapark](http://g.co/maps/gbdqg). Unfortunately my flight home leaves at 17:40 from Cologne Bonn Airport (CGN) so I have to leave before it's all over.

Approximately when do I have to leave Komed to get to the airport in time?
I will not have any luggage to check in and I guess that a taxi is the way to go…

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Hansaring station is about 10 minutes' walk from the conference building. (The KVB planner counts 14min, which is highly pessimistic, the distance is only 700m.) From that station, line S13 (see the [network map](http://www.kvb-koeln.de/german/fahrplan/linienplan.html)) gets you to the airport station in 17min; you can see the times on the [trip planner](http://auskunft.kvb-koeln.de/cgi-bin/assRoute.cgi). The S13 trains call at Hansaring at :18, :38 and :58. For a 17:50 flight inside the EU, arriving at 17:15 would be cutting it close, so I'd plan on taking the 16:38 train (arriving at the airport at 16:55), meaning you should be outside the building at about 16:25 (allow a couple of minutes to buy a ticket (€2.50), I don't think you can buy the ticket in advance).

I don't know what the traffic is at around 5pm in Cologne, but even with a clear way a taxi isn't going save a lot of time. The [airport website](http://www.koeln-bonn-airport.de/main.php?id=127&lang=1) states about 15 minutes to get to the center, to which you need to add some time for crossing the Rhine. Google's driving directions quote 23min, so in light traffic (but can you assume that? I don't know) you can leave at about 16:45 tops.

Comment: I can add some details: light traffic is not something you can count on at 5PM, especially because you're crossing the river; the ticket is €2.60 not 2.50, and make sure you buy one at the station from the machines (often red) because you can't on the train itself; the S13 is often very crowded; navigating the airport can take some time too, so check yourself in online with your phone or add more time; finally, I personally would also try to catch the train before the one I needed, just in case - if you miss it you know you'll be ok (just) with the next train.